# Trying to fix a "Trying to get property of non-object in * on line *" error

Tags: php, variables

**Im aware this code might be vulnerable to SQL injection, it doesn't matter, this is a private home project that will never go public**, the only person that can access this other than me is my dad and brother.

Im making a site where you press certain buttons, it sends you to a shop, but the shop doesn't load because of this error:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>shop.php</b> on line <b>12</b>
```

What could be wrong? I have tried looking for solutions on the internet but I found none.

This is the lines of code that this is affecting:

```
if (!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents("php://input");

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

$intShopId = $doc->getElementsByTagName('intShopId');
$shop_id = $intShopId->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

The last line in this case is line 12.

I know the reason of this is because `$intShopId` is not an object. I think it needs to be a global variable passed as a parameter, but in this individual case I cant figure out whats wrong and i would appreciate some help.

There might be some grammatical and/or spelling errors in the question here, I apologize if this is the case. I'm from Sweden.

Comment: Your english is actually better than a lot of Americans. Try `var_dump( $intShowId )` - and post what you get

Comment: `file_get_contents("php`.... If this is the actual markup and not a copy/paste error, it looks like the end of your statement is missing. Same for `$doc->getElementsByTagName('int`...

Comment: You have some unfinished lines. You should post the complete code of this section.

Comment: From the looks of things `nodeValue` isn't a property because `$intShopId->item(0)` didn't return an object.

Comment: Yep, and you should probably re-copy/paste your code, since it got cut off in some places, there -

Comment: The problem is that you are assuming that there are results. You should check for that first and take the appropriate action if there are none. What does your input look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is going to be with this line:

`$intShopId = $doc->getElementsByTagName('intShopId');`

since there is no such tag as an `<int>` -  or even any tag that even begins with that, then that method is returning null, or something else that isn't helpful.

you are probably looking to use a method like :

`$doc->getElementById('intShopId');`

Comment: right, but what I really meant was that there is no tag that even starts with `int` ---

Comment: If it's xml the tag could be anything that the creator of the document has defined.

Comment: It could --- and @jeroen is right --- so, is there markup in the XML that tags something as `<intShopId>` ?